# Replace back slashes with php replace

Tags: php

I would like to replace all the back slashes in my database but I am getting an error when I try to do so. Here is the code I use to replace (it works fine with all other characters)

```
if($queryType=='replace') {
    $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''\'\',\''Value to replace with'\')';
```

Comment: You're using MySQL's replace functiojn, not PHP's.

Comment: the variable says $sql, so I assume that he use later executing the query.

Comment: You accidentally editted the question.  You should change it back to what it was so others can learn from it as well.

Comment: Thank someone via comment, not by editing your question. When you edit your question you prevent someone else learning from your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the back slashes with back slashes. for example '\\'.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that did it. Have a cookie!!